# Is it true that the closure of an open subset $A$ such that $A\subset B$ where $B$ is closed is again a subset of $B$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm working on a problem with continuous functions, where I know that
$$A\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$$ with $A$ open and $f$ continuous. Now I'd like to consider the closure of $A$ and prove that 
$$\overline{A}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$$

More abstractly, the problem could be interpreted as: Suppose $A$ open and $B$ closed. Prove that $A\subset B\implies \overline{A}\subset B$.

Logically, this makes a lot of sense, but I'm not sure how I'd be able to prove this. It's worth noting that I'm using Rudin's definition of a limit point $p$ where there need to exists points $q$ in every neighbourhood around $p$, such that $p\neq q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers here are all very correct, but let me prove a related but much more general statement using the definition you mention. Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets with $A \subset B$ (note that they don't to be closed or open.), then we will prove that $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$. The proof is pretty straightforward. Let $p \in \overline{A}$, then for every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ we have that $(U\setminus\{p\} )\cap A \neq \emptyset$. Since $A \subset B$, we have $(U\setminus\{p\}) \cap A$ is contained in $(U\setminus\{p\}) \cap B$. As a result $(U\setminus\{p\}) \cap B$ is non-empty and $p \in \overline{B}$.

Answer (score 2):

The closure of any subset $A$ is the intersection of all subsets which contain $A$, hence is contained in any closed subset containing $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

$$
\bar{A} =_{\text{df}} \bigcap \{ C \mid A \subseteq C \wedge C \text{ is closed } \} \subseteq  B
$$

Comment: In other words: $\bar A$ is the $\subseteq$-minimal closed set containing $A$ as a subset. Since $B$ is a closed subset containing $A$ as a subset, we immediately get $\bar{A} \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline A$ is defined as

$$\overline A:=\bigcap_{C \text{ closed},\ A\subset C} C.$$

Since $B$ closed and $A\subset B$, you have that $B$ contain this intersection of sets.

So $\overline A\subset B$.